# Can I disable stemming / stop words filtering with MongoDB 4 text search, in C#

Tags: c#, mongodb

I would like to use the C# driver in MongoDB to make a full text search.

But I see that when I create the index, I can't select 'none' as a language.
I would like terms to be matched as they are and without removing the stop words either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a type

```
public class Entity
{
    public string Text;
}
```

You can do this:

```
var collection = new MongoClient().GetDatabase("test").GetCollection<Entity>("collection");
var indexKeysDefinition = new IndexKeysDefinitionBuilder<Entity>().Text(x => x.Text);
var createIndexOptions = new CreateIndexOptions { DefaultLanguage= "none" };
collection.Indexes.CreateOne(new CreateIndexModel<Entity>(indexKeysDefinition, createIndexOptions));
```